# What is a quantum analogue of the fact that the second fundamental group of every Lie group is trivial?

Tags: hopf-algebras, quantum-groups, noncommutative-geometry

What is an appropriate version of the following fact in terms of Hopf algebras and quantum groups:

*"For every connected Lie group $G$ the second fundamental group $\pi_2(G)$ is trivial?"*

Is there any research in this direction?

Comment: Well, it's true for non-connected Lie groups too. Also, you want "finite-dimensional" in there. The loop group of a Lie group has a nonzero $\pi_2$.

Comment: It should be kept in mind that maybe there is no analogue, in the sense that for non-classical quantum groups such a phenomenon does not occur.

Comment: quantum groups are more degenerations of (universal enveloping algebras of) Lie algebras than they are of Lie groups per se; is there a purely algebraic reformulation of the vanishing of $\pi_2$ statement?